# Pixel fill percentage by geometry for GLSL pixel shader

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader

Is it possible within a GLSL pixel shader to calculate from 0 to 1 how filled a pixel is by the geometry it is drawing?

Simple example: a cube in space will in 2d screen space be mostly 100% filled in the interior of the cube 2d projection, but around the boundary technically those pixels can be fractionally filled by the geometry itself (between 0.0 and 1.0)

I know multi sampling and anti aliasing deal with this problem, but this is a specific computational application where we can't afford much extra processing. I need to determine the actual decimal fill value.

In actual use cases the geometry is not simple and can not be reliably assumed to be a specific shape.

Looking into multi sampling as that's the only built in method I'm aware of that might help.

Comment: There is a `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH` that will compute the analytical coverage for triangles; but it's simply not useful for complicated shapes. Multi-sampling is your best bet if you want a fast and simple solution.

Comment: You just do `glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)` and OpenGL multiplies the fragment alpha by the analytical coverage. You don't have control over it. There's nothing to elaborate. I told you it's not useful. You should really give a better description of what problem you're trying to solve. E.g. you're talking about drawing a cube in space. But OpenGL doesn't know how to draw cubes; instead it rasterizes one triangle at a time. So if you truly need the coverage of the cube rather than individual primitives, OpenGL cannot do it for you. Also explain why multisampling doesn't cut the bill; it is cheap.

Comment: What does it mean? "state values", "inconsistent model"? You should be aware that even MS coverage you'll get in the fragment shader is prior to the depth test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH`

OpenGL does support analytical antialiasing for individual triangles with the `glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)`. However it applies the coverage to the alpha already after the fragment shader was executed. So to use it you'd need to rasterize one triangle at a time into a texture, and then run a second pass that would read the coverage values from that texture. The 'one triangle at a time' requirement is there to handle shared edges between adjacent triangles. Pixels along the shared edge would be rasterized twice, and it's not possible to combine the coverage to produce a 1.0 value along shared edges while staying correct everywhere else.

These limitations are in part why this feature of OpenGL is rarely used.

### Conservative raster + barycentric

An alternative to `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH` is to combine conservative rasterization with a manual check of barycentric coordinates. The most performant way would use `GL_NV_conservative_raster` and `GL_NV_fragment_shader_barycentric` extensions. Without the extensions, it's possible to achieve the same with unextended OpenGL using geometry shaders and interpolated attributes, albeit it will come with a performance hit.

This would remove the need to render one triangle at a time into a temporary texture, and instead allow processing all geometry in one batch. However, it still has the same problem that pixels on shared triangle edges would be rasterized multiple times with partial coverage values, and there isn't a way to combine those in a robust way.

### Multisampling

It seems that multisampling is what you need. In the end of the day, this is exactly what it was meant to solve. Surely, it won't give you the full precision that analytical coverage would give you, but it will handle shared edges correctly.

However, keep in mind that the coverage value that you get in the fragment shader precedes the depth test. Therefore you **will** need to implement a two pass solution. On the first pass render all the geometry into a temporary multisampling texture. Then run a second pass that reads the coverage (and other attributes) from the texture and runs whatever code you needed that coverage for.

---

This answer is based solely on your request of knowing the coverage value 'when rendering a cube' or 'other complex geometry'. Without knowing what you need this coverage values for I cannot offer any alternative ways of solving your actual problem.